# How to customize the volatile-highlights background color?

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I use the [volatitle-highlights-mode(VHL)](https://github.com/k-talo/volatile-highlights.el) to hightlights last edit region. But the background color of the VHL is much too light in color for the [solarized-theme](https://github.com/sellout/emacs-color-theme-solarized). So I want change the background color of the VHL.

I found the snippets from the VHL, as follow:

```
(defface vhl/default-face
  (cond
   ((or vhl/.xemacsp
        (vhl/.face-inheritance-possible-p))
    '((((class color) (background light))
       (:background "yellow1"))
      (((class color) (background dark))
       (:background "SkyBlue4"))
      (t :inverse-video t)))
   (t
    '((t
       :inherit secondary-selection
       ))))
    "Face used for volatile highlights."
    :group 'volatile-highlights)
```

this snippets specify the color of the VHL background, so how can I customize the background color in my .emacs.d to override the default VHL background color.

Snippets welcome! Thanks.

Comment: I collect add-ons by git submodule mechanism, if I change the values directly, it will cause some error while I update submodels next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just use `M-x customize-face RET vhl/default-face`.  It does not matter how the face is defined: you can still use Customize to customize it.

Answer (score 0):

The code above looks strange: It seems to check whether face inheritance is possible and, if not, try to inherit from the `secondary-selection` face (!!)

Anyway, the easiest thing to do is use `customize-face`, like wvxvw suggested in the comments to your question. I don't quite understand your response to his answer: setting a face that doesn't exist won't cause any error. However, if you're worried, you can cut the `(custom-set-face .... )` form that appears in your .emacs and stick it in a file in .emacs.d: the warning about only using one instance in your .emacs is so that the customize infrastructure knows how to edit the file.